# Javascript addEventListener keyDown stops input from being editable

Tags: javascript, html

I've been making a game, and I want an input box beside my canvas. I have finally figured out that

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = true; 
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;    
});
```

has stopped me from being able to edit the input box

```
<input type='text' id='input' value='asdf'>
```

Any solutions where both can work?
I've tried putting the addEventListener on a div surrounding the 
canvas' yet it still doesn't work, unless I comment out that code.

Comment: Why not put another event handler on the input event and do `stopPropagation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the element that the event was triggered on is **not** input.

Here is the change to your code:

```js
var keys = {}
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if (e.srcElement.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = true; 
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  if (e.srcElement.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;    
  }
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' value='asdf'>
```